# Service Fabric installation location on vm scale set

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-vm-scale-set

Is it preferred to go on the temp drive D:? It seems like that's the case because it's faster HD, but wouldn't this space be lost in a reboot/VM move? Would the VMScaleSet re-install service fabric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Service Fabric stores state on local, ephemeral disks, meaning that if
>   the virtual machine is moved to a different host, the data does not
>   move with it. In normal operation, that is not a problem as the new
>   node is brought up to date by other nodes.

[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-common-questions)

The cluster definition is on the C: drive, the state is on D:. The cluster definition will survive reboots. And because the state is stored redundantly, SF can provision new nodes with the state, provided there are sufficient operational nodes still running.

Comment: So in my ARM template it's set to D:\svcfab, that appears like it's installing the app/cluster definition to the D:?

Comment: if you're talking about `"dataPath": "D:\SvcFab",`, this is about the data (the state).